# Not able to discover CBServices I am advertising

Tags: ios, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am creating a custom CBService and adding them to the CBPeripheralManager. I am advertising the service along with the Advertisement data. But I am not able to see the service I created in the Light Blue app. The Light Blue app shows two services which I don't know what they are and I didn't add those. The advertisement data is shown but not the service. Below is my implementation of creating a service and advertising it in Xamarin:

```
void AdvertiseData()
    {
        var uui = new CBUUID[] { CBUUID.FromString("E20A39F4-73F5-4BC4-A12F-17D1AD07A961") };

        var nsArray = NSArray.FromObjects(uui);
        var nsObject = NSObject.FromObject(nsArray);

        var manufacturerDataBytes = new byte[6] { 5, 255, 76, 0, 25, 35 };

        var advertisementData = new NSDictionary(

             CBAdvertisement.DataLocalNameKey, "id1",
             CBAdvertisement.DataServiceUUIDsKey, nsObject,
             CBAdvertisement.DataManufacturerDataKey, NSData.FromArray(manufacturerDataBytes));


        try
        {
            var newService = new CBMutableService(CBUUID.FromString("1F3A8B1E-4BAA-45DA-B3A4-7A19DDC86305"), false);//1F3A8B1E-4BAA-45DA-B3A4-7A19DDC86305
            newService.Characteristics = new CBCharacteristic[]
              {
                new CBMutableCharacteristic(CBUUID.FromString("906377DD-F782-448C-9A65-796B48E10894"),//906377DD-F782-448C-9A65-796B48E10894
                CBCharacteristicProperties.Read, "FooChar",
                CBAttributePermissions.Readable),
                new CBMutableCharacteristic(CBUUID.FromString("2B77EC99-BE87-45D3-863C-599D5202E4C0"),//2B77EC99-BE87-45D3-863C-599D5202E4C0
                CBCharacteristicProperties.Write, null,
                CBAttributePermissions.Writeable)
              };

            cbPeriphMang.AddService(newService);
            //cbPeriphMang.RemoveAllServices();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }


        if (cbPeriphMang.Advertising) cbPeriphMang.StopAdvertising();

        cbPeriphMang.StartAdvertising(new StartAdvertisingOptions(){LocalName="alpha", ServicesUUID = new CBUUID[] { CBUUID.FromString("1F3A8B1E-4BAA-45DA-B3A4-7A19DDC86305")} } );
    }
```

Comment: Your `newService` should be a property so that a strong reference is held; by making it a local variable it will be released once your function exits. You should also make sure that the peripheral manager is in the powered on state before attempting to advertise your service.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running the LightBlue app on another iOS device. In my experience iOS caches a lot of BLE data including services and characteristics. If the peripheral changes any service or characters (or adds or deletes) then iOS will not see those changes until you restart bluetooth on the iOS device where LightBlue is running. In some cases all I need to do is turn bluetooth off/on but in other cases I had to restart the device completely. If you scan the Apple developer forums you will find other people reporting the same problem and same workaround.